# Python queue with a delay time

Tags: python, django, queue, twisted

I have a web server running on Django.
Users can create events postponed in time.

These events must be recorded in queue and processed on another server.

Initially I thought to take the Twisted. something like:

```
#client - django server
factory = pb.PBClientFactory()
reactor.connectTCP(server_ip, server_port, factory)
d = factory.login(credentials.UsernamePassword(login, paswd),)
d.addCallbacks(self.good_connected,self.bad_connected)
d.addCallback(self.add_to_queue)
reactor.run()

def add_to_queue(self, p)
    p.callRemote("pickup", data)


#server - twisted server
def perspective_pickup(self, data)
    reactor.callLater(timeout, self.pickup_from_queue)
```

But now I have big doubts about this approach. Maybe do not use twisted? or connect it with Django differently

Comment: You probably want to look at Celery.

Comment: Daniel you should really add that as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run twisted inside of Django is not a good idea anyway. So, try [Celery](http://celeryproject.org/) or run HTTP server with twisted and use urllib on django side to send data to twisted server.